# TinyMCE - setting or configuration to avoid sanitising source code

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I am using TinyMCE - 6.1.2 version. I would like to retain all the contents entered in TinyMCE as it is (especially while using 'Source Code' option).

Adding the below configuration helps in the majority of the scenarios.

```
verify_html : false,
```

But some values like action getting automatically stripped:

```
<input type='hidden' name='action' value=''>
```

is getting stripped to:

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **bug in TinyMCE** and the same has been confirmed -
[TinyMCE removing 'action' word even after setting verify_html to false](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/8306)

Code Flow:

- setContentString

  - parse

    - parseAndSanitizeWithContext

      - DOMPurify.sanitize *(iterate through each node)*

        - _sanitizeElements *(checks for specific condition and removes the node. There are no configuration to control this. Also element specific validation is done using the hook - uponSanitizeElement )*
        - _sanitizeAttributes *(similar to _sanitizeElements, but in this case attributes are removed)*

If your element or node is getting removed, please debug the **_sanitizeElements** or **_sanitizeAttributes** functions respectively.